# Choice an information in a list and add in a database with PHP

Tags: php, html

I've a list of choice (see the picture)[image: Example of the choice]

The user choose a book and click on "Ajouter" and it will be add in my database.
If the user click on the first button "ajouter" how can i get the data?

Here's my code to generate the html:

```
<?
function generateHTMLView($xmlBook)
{
    $date = time();
    $owner = $_SESSION['user'];
    echo('
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table class="table" id="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Titre</th>
                <th>Editeur</th>
                <th>Auteur</th>
                <th>ISBN</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            ');
    $id=0;
    foreach ($xmlBook->data as $item) {
        $title = $item->title;
        $lengthTitle=strlen($title);
        if($lengthTitle >30){
            $numberToDelete='-'.$lengthTitle+30;
            $titleTemp=mb_substr($title,0,$numberToDelete).'...';
        } else {
            $titleTemp=$title;
        }
        $publisher = $item->publisher_name;
        foreach ($item->author_data as $authorData) {
            $author = $authorData->name;
        }

            $pages = $item->physical_description_text;
            $resume = $item->summary;
            $resUn = addcslashes($resume, ",'-");
            $isbn13 = $item->isbn13;
            $languageB = $item->language;
            $this->consctructArrayBooks($id,$title,$isbn13,$publisher,$author,$pages,$languageB,$date,$owner,$resume);
            $id++;
            $_POST['id']=$title;
            echo('
              <form method="POST" >
                 <tr>
                    <td>' . $titleTemp . '</td>
                    <td>' . $publisher . '</td>
                    <td>' . $author . '</td>
                    <td>' . $isbn13 . '</td>
                    <td><button type="submit">Ajouter</button></td>
                   </tr>
                   </form>
                   ');
      }
      echo ('
        </tbody>
           </table>
           <hr>
           </div>
           </div>
          ');
}
```

Comment: `i've no idea how to know which book the user want to insert.` Then, how we will know ??

Comment: Good to see your update, then why can't you write the button click action ?

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Ok, then you should write code to detect when button is pressed !

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen i'm using a form in my html code. I just don't know how I can get the value of the array.

Comment: Cool, What you need to do is to trigger `$("#yourButtonId").click(function(){`

Comment: You want me to give you some example ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Yes, it will be really cool

Comment: @loi219 Added the detailed answer for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the 5 Steps composed for you

**Step 1 :**

In the loop you have declare a class and id

```
<td><button class="triggerClass" id="<?php echo $item->id?>">Ajouter</button></td>
```

`Note 1 :` Here i have the class name as `triggerClass` you shall use any name that you like.

`Note 2 :` I am considering `$item->id` is under the `foreach` loop and it will have dynamic values in each iteration

**Step 2 :**

Detect the click event of class

$(".triggerClass").click(function(){
    //You can reach here whenever the class `.triggerClass` is clicked
    });

**Step 3 :**

Find the class's id

alert($(this).attr('id'));

`Note 3 :` If you place the above code inside the click function then you will get the alert of the id's value which you clicked

**Step 4 :**

Send the id's value to the php script through jquery ajax call

Here's the simple jquery ajax call

```
var yourId = $(this).attr('id');
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "yourScript.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { id : yourId },
  dataType: "html"
});
```

**Step 5 :**

In the php script get the value and store it in database

Inside the `yourScript.php` Just get the `$_POST['id']` and store to the database by implementing simple insert operation

That's it :) Hope this helps you

Comment: It really help me, I'm going to test it

Comment: I'm trying to made the code you send me working. The POST request is send but i don't know how to get it in my php code. 
If I do an `echo $_POST['id']` in my page nothing happen.
Maybe can you help to understand how to do that, it's the first time I use Ajax

Comment: Sure, Can u say what is the output in console

Comment: The POST data is send but there is no output in the console and there is an error when I do `echo $_POST['id'];` it's normal because id is not initialized but when I click on "Ajouter" nothing happened.

Comment: Then can you do initialize and then echo ?

Comment: I was trying but i don't know how to do that. Like do I have to reload the page when the user click on the button?

Comment: Nope, .. you have done all the jquery actions in document.ready and included js library ?

Comment: Thank for your quick reply.
No there are not in document.ready, I going to correct this.

Comment: Yes, Can you say what happens after including in document ready ?

Comment: Here's the js you gave me `<script>
document.ready(
                $(".triggerClass").click(function(){

                    var yourId = $(this).attr("id");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/books/SearchBooks.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: { id : yourId },
                        dataType: "html"
                    });

                   });
                );

                </script>`

And after that I do an `echo $_POST['id']` and it return `Undefined index: id in ...`

Comment: I think it's because i'm sending the data on the same where I execute the script, but if I execute in an other PHP page, i lost the array of the books from the search query?

Comment: I wil reply in few hours its 1.30 am for me

Comment: No problem, i'm just investigating and post what I found.
Have a good night

Comment: No, i'm stuck with the same problem.
I think it's because i'm sending the data on the same where I execute the script, but if I execute in an other PHP page, i lost the array of the books from the search query?

Comment: You want to return the data from same page or somewhere else ?

Comment: If I can in the same page because my arrays are initialized in this page.

Comment: Don't worry about data, you shall store it in session or pass to the target page

Answer (score 1):

If you make your "Ajouter" buttons an array indexed by item number eg.

```
<input type="submit" value="Ajouter" name="ajouter[1]" />
<input type="submit" value="Ajouter" name="ajouter[2]" />
<input type="submit" value="Ajouter" name="ajouter[3]" />
```

then your server code can just walk the array to determine which one was pressed.